# xsl:template match="//[要素]" と match="[要素]" の違い

Tags: xsl, xslt

`<xsl:template match="//p" >` と `<xsl:template match="p" >` の違いが良くわかりません。
わかりやすくご解説可能な方がいらっしゃいましたら宜しくお願いいたします。

例えば以下のような stylesheet の場合、`<xsl:template match="//p" >` が優先して処理されます。

```xsl
<!-- xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <p p="1">
        <p p="2">
            <p p="3"/>
        </p>
    </p>
</root>

<!-- stylesheet -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="//p" >
        <xsl:copy-of select="."></xsl:copy-of>
        <xsl:value-of select="'//p'"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p" >
        <xsl:copy-of select="."></xsl:copy-of>
        <xsl:value-of select="'p'"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: まず御自身で仕様を参照して調べたらどうでしょうか？以下にあります．6.4 Conflict Resolution for Template Rules  https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#conflict

Comment: 膨大な英語の仕様の中からなかなか見つけられなかったので・・ここには初歩的な質問をしないほうがいいということは良くわかりました。

Comment: 膨大な仕様のすべてを覚えるのではなく、およそ何がどこにあるかがわかってくれば問題を解くカギになります．仕様のありかがわかったらそれを読んだ結果を質問に反映させて絞り込んでゆくことにより、問題解決を一歩づつ進めることができるでしょう．

Comment: @taruga さん、怖がらせてしまっていたらすいません。おそらく tmakita さんは回答に至るまでの道筋を案内しようとなさっていたのだと思います。厳しい印象を与えていたら申し訳ないです。このサイトでは初歩的なご質問も大歓迎ですし、そのご質問に回答がつくことで他の方が同じことを調べる手間が大幅に省けます。そもそも仕様書をちゃんと参照して考えなければいけない疑問はそこまで初歩的ではないようにも思います。ご質問が投稿されなければ回答することもできないので、是非今後ともご質問頂ければと思います。よろしくお願いいたします :)

Comment: @nekketsuuuさん親切なお言葉を頂きまして大変感謝いたします。しかし@tmakitaさんのコメントを見ると、やはり仕様書から該当箇所を発見し、それを理解して質問することを示唆しており、対照的なご意見と捉えられました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ご質問の結果はテンプレートの`@match`に記述するパターンから導かれる既定のテンプレートのプライオリティが異なるためにこのようなものとなります．

XSLT 2.0勧告の [6.4 Conflict Resolution for Template Rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#conflict) によれば、

- `match="p"`は`match="element(p)"`と等価で、`priority="0"`となります．
- `match="//p"`は`match="document-node()/descendant-or-self::node()/p"`と等価で、`priority="0.5"`となります．

このため`match="//p"`の方が優先度が高くなり、p要素にマッチした際にこちらのテンプレートが採用されます．

これは次のように意図的に`@priority`を変えてテストしてみることで確認できます．

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="//p" priority="0">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <xsl:value-of select="'//p'"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <xsl:value-of select="'p'"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

とすれば例えばSaxonの場合次のような警告が出ます．

Severity: warning
Description: Ambiguous rule match for /root/p[1](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#conflict) Matches both "element(Q{}p)" on line 11 of file:/C:/Users/toshi/OneDrive/Documents/test/xslt/20180622-pattern/test2.xsl and "document-node()//element(Q{}p)" on line 6 of file:/C:/Users/toshi/OneDrive/Documents/test/xslt/20180622-pattern/test2.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="//p">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <xsl:value-of select="'//p'"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p" priority="0.5">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <xsl:value-of select="'p'"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

とすれば、

Severity: warning
Description: Ambiguous rule match for /root/p[1](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#conflict) Matches both "element(Q{}p)" on line 11 of file:/C:/Users/toshi/OneDrive/Documents/test/xslt/20180622-pattern/test3.xsl and "document-node()//element(Q{}p)" on line 6 of file:/C:/Users/toshi/OneDrive/Documents/test/xslt/20180622-pattern/test3.xsl

の警告となります．

上記により、パターンの記述により、テンプレートには勧告で定められた既定の`@priority`が適用されることがわかるでしょう．